# What's the best data structure for mapping ranges to values?

Tags: typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for an efficiency data structure that provides following API (I'll write it in TypeScript but it's language irrelevant):

```
interface RangeMap<T> {
  set(range: [number, number], value: T): void;
  get(val: number): T;
}
```

As you can see, there are two public functions in the interface, one is the `set` function, that let user associates a range to a target value, whose type is determined by the generic parameter, `T`. After doing this, user can query the value back by using the `get` function with a number that is in range. for example:

```
let map = new RangeMap();

// associate a range to a value
map.set([0, 3], 1);

// It should output `1`, since number 2 is in the range of [0, 3]
console.log(map.get(2)); 

// It should output `null` for 10 is out of range.
console.log(map.get(10));
```

Currently I implements it with `Array`. For those don't familiar with TS/JS, the array here is more like the C++'s `vector` instead of plain old C array. The range and value are stored in the internal array in pair. A linear search will be processed every time user calls the `get(val: number): T` member function, examinating if any range in the array includes given number, and return the correspondent value if it's true. This is probably the most intuitive yet brute-force method.

I am looking for a data structure that, can do both insertion and query in `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` time, just like the classic map that are implemented with a hash table or a balanced binary tree. If it can be hardly implemented, I can compromise with one of two operation in `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` time.

I once wanted to use the build-in `Map` as solution, but found out it is not suitable at all. Because the there are infinitive numbers exists in a range, and obviously I can add every possible number in the target map.

If anyone have some idea about the problem, please leave an answer below, thanks very much!

--

Edit:

Just presume ranges shouldn't overlap each other.

Comment: Would you have overlapping ranges? E.g., `[0, 4] -> 4` and `[1, 5] -> 2`? If you have them, how would `get(3)` return? Or would you expect no overlaps?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this with a sorted map from number to value (`std::map` in C++, or `TreeMap` in Java).  The keys are all the numbers at which the value changes.  For example, if you do:

```
set([1,4],100)
set([3,8],200)
```

you get mappings

```
1 -> 100
3 -> 200
9 -> null
```

To get the value for any particular number, you search the tree for the closest key less than or equal.  (using `std::map:lower_bound` or `TreeSet.floor()`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map that maintains the order of keys, e.g. a `TreeMap` in Java, to map the low value of each interval to the interval. To recover the interval for a query value `v` you'd first recover the greatest key `k` less than or equal to `v`. If no such key exists (`v` is less than the min interval) then return null. If not, recover the interval associated with `k` and check if `v` is less than the high value. If so return the interval, else return null.

This is somewhat similar to Matt Timmermans [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68529504/6438819), but you only have to insert the low value of each interval, as the cost of the additional check when you recover an interval.

Some example Java code. It seems a [version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-treemap) of `TreeMap` is available for Typescript.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] is = {{1,4,1}, {5,8,2}, {9,12,3}};
    
    TreeMap<Integer, Pair> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for(int[] i: is)
        map.put(i[0], new Pair(i[1], i[2]));
    
    for(int i=is[0][0]-1;i<is[is.length-1][1]+1; i++)
        System.out.println(i + " " + lookup(map, i));
}

static Integer lookup(TreeMap<Integer, Pair> map, int v)
{
    Integer k = map.floorKey(v);
    if(k != null) 
    {       
        Pair p = map.get(k);        
        if(v < p.a) return p.b;
    }
    return null;
}

static class Pair
{
    int a, b;
    public Pair(int a_, int b_) 
    {
        a = a_; b = b_;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 null
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 null
5 2
6 2
7 2
8 null
9 3
10 3
11 3
12 null
```